# How to point two different domain names to a single website?

Tags: dns, cross-domain, hosting, multiple-domains

I have on website but this site has no meaning full domain name but have good ranking on internet. I want to make this like this website will be pointed by two different domain names.

please suggest me that how can i do this. please give me easy steps for doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under each of your domains you should have DNS settings so go there and put the same DNS for each domain or you can set DNS for the first on and redirection for the second one.

Comment: Thanks for responding , can i use site logo according to domain name ? i mean two different logo for two domain name

Comment: @user2265462 If you setup DNS for both then with a little JS you can check on which domain you are and load different logo. However this is bad idea because the site doesn't change it's the same in both cases so why you want to change logo? Another reason why this is bad is that performance goes down.

Answer (score 2):

You can just setup DNS records for both domains to point to the IP of your server.

If you have virtual hosts configured on your server, you may need to create an entry for both domain names.