# How to do a wordpress url redirect, olddomain.com to new.domain.com

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

Here is my situation:

I have a website ( live ) which user accesses as:

http://olddomain.com/news

I have another website which user accesses like:

http://newdomain.com/news

(/news being an example of a page of the website).

These are basically 2 different websites, but with exact same content.

I would like if user accesses to the website by the old domain: http://olddomain.com/news

to be automatically redirected to http://newdomain.com/news

Is there any plugin or htaccess rules or other to make this work?

I can't find any information about this, it will be amazing to have some highlight about that!

Thank you for all your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this .htaccess in olddomain.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thank you for your time,

unfortunately, it seems to not change anything, if i write http://olddomain.com/page it keeps going to http://olddomain.com/page instead of http://newdomain.com/page

Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> these are basically 2 different websites - but with the exact same content

If eventually you are going to redirect user for every page on oldsite.com , then you can point olddomain.com to newdomain.com

check here:
[How to point two different domain names to a single website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353159/how-to-point-two-different-domain-names-to-a-single-website)

Edit:
Just found this.If you want to redirect users for every page on olddomain then you can try something from here: [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately, I can't change the DNS of the domains for some other reasons....:/is there any other way around  ? htacess ? plugins ? other ? 

Thank you :)